# Restricting Access to MVC Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC website where I've established a system of Permissions. There are, for example, some links that are hidden when the current user does not have sufficient permissions. However, if they manually type in the URL of that link, they can still access the content.

I know I can use the `[Authorize]` attribute to prevent users without the right user role, but how can I implement my own attribute to block an action for users that do not meet custom requirements, without having to write a manual check inside each of those actions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write a custom `Authorize` attribute and override the `AuthorizeCore` method where you could place your custom authorization logic:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authroized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authroized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // at this stage the base authorization process has passed.
        // now implement your custom authorization logic and return true or false

        // here you have access to the HttpContext and as a consequence to all
        // request and route parameters so you could implement any 
        // authorization logic you want

        // And of course if you want a completely custom authorization logic 
        // ignoring the base functionality don't call the base method above
        // but completely override anything here
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is to decorate the corresponding controllers/actions with this custom attribute.

Comment: Thanks Darin. The only issue is that my filter may need to work in combination with AuthorizeAttribute (where both attributes are used but with different values). Are there issues with deriving from `FilterAttribute` directly?

Comment: Yes, you could derive from `FilterAttribute` and also implement the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface by putting the custom authorization logic in the `OnAuthorization` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Membership, you can configure a RoleProvider and give your users roles.

Then, you can use the Roles property on the AuthorizeAttribute to check for a role.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin, SuperUser")]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using both ASP.NET Membership and the Authorize attribute. But neither answer the question above for dealing with custom criteria.

Comment: How does it not?  You're looking at inheriting MembershipProvider.  Look into also inheriting RoleProvider, and adding that as a RoleManager in web.config.  THis way, you make your own roles and redirect to an 'Access Denied' or whatever if you don't want them there

Comment: Well, I am not looking at inheriting MembershipProvider. I simply want to provide similar functionality, except with some custom logic that does not map directly to my list of user roles. And I do not have the option of mapping directly to my roles because I am also using membership roles.

Comment: Valid point.  I'll leave this here for others that may find benefit in this, but since you're doing custom authorization, @Darin's answer is best.